# How to remove all packages from a conda environment - but keep environment itself

Tags: conda, mamba

Conda environments are defined by the packages installed in them *and* extra metadata like which channels to use, channel priority, the subdir (whether to use `osx-64` or `osx-arm`).

I would like to uninstall *only* the packages but keep the environment configuration alive.

I know I can delete the entire environment with `conda remove --all -n ENV_NAME` - but using this command I loose the metadata.

It is quite likely that no `conda` CLI command exists to do what I want (at least [`conda remove`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html) doesn't seem to do this). But is there a workaround, maybe listing all packages and feeding them to `conda remove -n ENV_NAME [PACKAGE_NAME ...]`.

I opened a feature request to add an option to keep empty environments around: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/12485

Answer (score 1):

With a little help from our friends...

```bash
mamba list | grep -v '#' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs mamba remove -d
```

> ⚠️ The `-d` flag is added for safety, since otherwise **this will not prompt user for review**! Remove it to execute. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Nice! So `mamba` only removes the packages, not the environment? I get an error when I run this, due to `__osx` and `__unix` special packages: 
`KeyError: PackageRecord(_hash=-472553835912562056, name='__osx', version='13.2.1', build='0', build_number=0, channel=Channel("@"), subdir='osx-64', fn='__osx', md5='12345678901234567890123456789012', package_type='virtual_system')`

Comment: This lists out all the packages and asks to remove them - `conda` should have same behavior. If mutex packages are a problem, maybe use grep to skip them, e.g., `grep -v '^[#_]'`.